# Creating Random sorted dates from date range in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Current DataFrame:

```
    Account_ID  Transaction_Type    Transaction_Date
0   10001        B                      
1   10001        B                      
2   10001        B                      
3   10001        B                      
4   10002        D                      
5   10002        D                      
6   10002        D                      
7   10003        F                      
8   10003        F                      
9   10004        H
```

I am trying to create random 'Transaction Date' in the range of '2018-06-30' to '2018-11-30' which is sorted for group of 'Account ID'. For each group of 'Account ID' random date should consider the specified range.

Expected Output:

```
    Account_ID  Transaction_Type    Transaction_Date
0   10001        B                  2018-06-30  
1   10001        B                  2018-07-15  
2   10001        B                  2018-07-22  
3   10001        B                  2018-09-14  
4   10002        D                  2018-07-02  
5   10002        D                  2018-07-29  
6   10002        D                  2018-10-20  
7   10003        F                  2018-07-07  
8   10003        F                  2018-11-11  
9   10004        H                  2018-06-30
```

I am trying with below logic.

Group by on accountid, get the count of each group, generate random date list in the mentioned range with sample of count for each group and assign list elements to 'Transaction_Date' series with loc.
Any better way please suggest. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would define a custom function, and apply it with `groupby().transform`. The function does the following:

1: gets the number of days between the start and end days

2: gets *n* random integers (*n* is the size of each group, and the integers represent number of days after the start day), and sorts them

3: adds those random integers as a timedelta of days to the start date.

```
start_date = pd.to_datetime('2018-06-30')
end_date = pd.to_datetime('2018-11-30')

def gen_rand_date(group, start_date = start_date, end_date = end_date):
    # step 1 in description above:
    days = (end_date - start_date).days
    # step 2:
    d = pd.np.sort(pd.np.random.choice(range(days), len(group)))
    # step 3:
    return start_date + pd.to_timedelta(d,unit='D')

df['Transaction_Date'] = df.groupby('Account_ID').transform(lambda x: gen_rand_date(x))

>>> df
   Account_ID Transaction_Type Transaction_Date
0       10001                B       2018-07-19
1       10001                B       2018-08-12
2       10001                B       2018-08-27
3       10001                B       2018-09-29
4       10002                D       2018-10-23
5       10002                D       2018-11-09
6       10002                D       2018-11-14
7       10003                F       2018-08-03
8       10003                F       2018-09-10
9       10004                H       2018-09-16
```

Comment: Awesome @sacul!! Thank you so much!